# Make jQuery code run on page-change and load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a jquery code that inserts and prepends breadcrumbs on certain pages. I'm injecting this code through a third party tool where I can write JS. I only want these breadcrumbs for certain pages.

This was my original code that worked fine on desktop:

```
var style = document.createElement("style");
style.id = "Imdone";
style.textContent = ".breadcrumbs-mai{color:#555; font-size:14px; width:100%; padding:10px 5px;font-weight:200;}";
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(style);

require(['jquery'], function($){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var bread = $('<div class="breadcrumbs-mai"><a href="https://www.norli.no">Hjem </a>/ <a href="https://www.norli.no/">Test </a>/ <a href="https://www.norli.no/">Test2 </a>/ <a href="https://www.norli.no/">test 3</a>/ <a style="color:#000; font-weight:600;" href="https://www.norli.no/">Test 4 </a></div>').prependTo('#page-title-heading');
  });
});
```

On mobile it didn't load after changing category by clicking the `li` items. So I added `$('body').change(runbread);` to make it appear when switching category(page does not refresh on mobile when clicking a category, only does so on desktop).

But now, it loads twice for mobile and three times on desktop.

Here is my JS:

```
var style = document.createElement("style");
style.id = "Imdone";
style.textContent = ".breadcrumbs-mai{color:#555; font-size:14px; width:100%; padding:10px 5px;font-weight:200;}";
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(style);

require(['jquery'], function($){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").change(runbread);
  });
  
  function runbread(){
    var bread = $('<div class="breadcrumbs-mai"><a href="https://www.norli.no">Test </a>/ <a href="https://www.norli.no/">Test 2 </a>/ <a href="https://www.norli.no/">Test 3 </a>/ <a href="https://www.norli.no/">Test 4</a>/ <a style="color:#000; font-weight:600;" href="https://www.norli.no/">Test 5</a></div>').prependTo('#page-title-heading');
  }
});
```

How can I make sure it doesn't load several times?

So, on mobile it should load on page-load AND re-load again when a `li` item is clicked(no page-reload, only content change). On desktop only on page-load.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Inside your `runbread` function do `$('#page-title-heading .breadcrumbs-mai').remove()` at the start. IT will remove the "old" records

Comment: But im a bit unsure why you want to use `change` function for the body

Comment: When I view the HTML in the console, it's the only thing I see changing when clicking the categories. Should I use ```change``` on something else?
I added the ```remove```function in the runbread function, it removed all 3.

I added the code tghat worked fine on desktop before I tried fixing it for mobile.

Comment: Did you at the remove at the start of runbreak()`?

Comment: I added it at the bottom, but I tried at the start now and it worked! Is this safe to use it like this? Thanks for the help! I'm gonna test some stuff and see if it's consistent

Comment: Yes it's safe to use. Basically it just removes any that might exist before addin a new one.

Comment: Allright, thank you for your help. You can post it as an answer and I'll mark it for you, as this solved the issue of loading the breadcrumbs twice, and 'thrice'... Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244336/discussion-between-r-srour-and-carsten-lovbo-andersen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `$('#page-title-heading .breadcrumbs-mai').remove()` to the start of your `runbread` function.

This will remove any other `.breadcrumbs` that might have been added before.